# End of data error using PyRserve

Tags: python, r, rserve, pyrserve

I am calling an R script file from python using pyrserve. I have rserve running. At arbitrary points in the R script, pyrserve gives an error and quits:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptV2.py", line 272, in <module>
    rConn.eval("source(file.PropensityFlow)")
  File "/Users/dipayanmaiti/Py3.3venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyRserve/rconn.py", line 47, in decoCheckIfClosed
    return func(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/dipayanmaiti/Py3.3venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyRserve/rconn.py", line 119, in eval
    return rparse(src, atomicArray=atomicArray)
  File "/Users/dipayanmaiti/Py3.3venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyRserve/rparser.py", line 539, in rparse
    return rparser.parse()
  File "/Users/dipayanmaiti/Py3.3venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyRserve/rparser.py", line 349, in parse
    self.lexer.readHeader()
  File "/Users/dipayanmaiti/Py3.3venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyRserve/rparser.py", line 94, in readHeader
    self.responseCode = struct.unpack(b'<i', self.read(3) + b'\x00')[0]
  File "/Users/dipayanmaiti/Py3.3venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyRserve/rparser.py", line 149, in read
    raise EndOfDataError()
pyRserve.rparser.EndOfDataError
```

I have set `rserv.conf` to the following:

```
maxinbuf 20000000
maxsendbuf 0
```

Does anybody know why this happens? This looks like some buffer problem, because the R script runs by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is a late answer, but in such situations it is useful to run Rserve in debug mode so its output can be monitored in a separate shell.

```
R CMD Rserve.dbg
```

In some rare cases I've seen Rserve printing warnings to the console, and when this happened the command sent thru pyRserve didn't return any value from Rserve - which led to the 'EndOfDataError' above.